# Swift 3: 'if let' optional binding error

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I am working in Swift 3, and am experiencing trouble with the following if let test:

```
let plistUrl = Bundle.main().urlForResource("Books", withExtension: "plist")

if let plistData = try Data(contentsOf: plistUrl!) {
  ...some code
}
```

The compiler is showing the following error on the if let statement:

```
Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Data'
```

What is the issue here, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`try` doesn't return an optional. `try?` does.

Comment: That did the trick! I knew it had to be something stupidly simple.

Answer (score 0):

With Swift, the proper way to handle errors and retrieve data from methods that may throw errors is explained in the [Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html) section of the "Swift programming language".

Therefore, according to your needs, you may choose between one of the 3 following patterns to solve your problem.

---

## 1. Retrieve data and handle errors using `do-catch` and `try` keyword

> You use a `do-catch` statement to handle errors by running a block of code. If an error is thrown by the code in the `do` clause, it is matched against the `catch` clauses to determine which one of them can handle the error.

Usage:

```
let plistUrl = Bundle.main().urlForResource("Books", withExtension: "plist")!

let plistData: Data?
do {
    plistData = try Data(contentsOf: plistUrl)
} catch {
    print(error as NSError)
    plistData = nil
}
    
print(plistData)
```

---

## 2. Retrieve data and convert errors to optional values using `try?` keyword

> You use `try?` to handle an error by converting it to an optional value. If an error is thrown while evaluating the `try?` expression, the value of the expression is nil.

Usage:

```
let plistUrl = Bundle.main().urlForResource("Books", withExtension: "plist")!
    
guard let plistData = try? Data(contentsOf: plistUrl) else {
    return
}
    
print(plistData)
```

---

## 3. Retrieve data and disable error propagation using `try!` keyword

> Sometimes you know a throwing function or method won’t, in fact, throw an error at runtime. On those occasions, you can write `try!` before the expression to disable error propagation and wrap the call in a runtime assertion that no error will be thrown. If an error actually is thrown, you’ll get a runtime error.

Usage:

```
let plistUrl = Bundle.main().urlForResource("Books", withExtension: "plist")!
    
let plistData = try! Data(contentsOf: plistUrl)
    
print(plistData)
```